# Jquery grid template for EPG (Electronic program guides)

Tags: jquery, xml, grid, epg

Does anyone know any free JQuery template for serving EPG needs? I'm getting XML file with all necessary info (channel's name, title, description, start and end time etc.) and want to present it in some fancy way. Good examples are: [example1](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/guide) and [example2](http://www.sbb.rs/epg/grid).

Many thanks.